# Where should i place the helptext on a form designed for tablets?

Tags: forms, mobile-web

Im designing a form for tablets.  The helptext needs to appear dynamically (i.e. on focus on the field) & cannot be hidden behind help icons etc.

I have space to allow the helptext to appear on the right of the field form and considering putting it here. However, know helptext usually appears underneath the field for smartphones.

Any best practise advice? 1 or 2. thank you.[image]

Comment: Could you show a screen or mockup for the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Showing help text to the right may pose a few issues like

1. For a long message text you may have to wrap the message several times. So it may appear like a block of text instead of a message.
2. If the message text lengths keep varying based on the field in concern then these block sizes will keep changing invariably with the fields
3. You may not be able to use the complete screen estate for the field (if required) since you may have to provide space for the message to be displayed (assuming you don't plan on showing the message over the field itself)

I would suggest the approach of showing the messages below since it would help overcome the above mentioned issues and most of all make the UI consistent and neat improving the UX.

However just for a thought, while filling a form we fill it top to bottom so won't it seem helpful to show help text above the field since the last updating field will be the bottom most (or screen center)in the flow.